# Passing CMD via PSEXEC to a remote computer via .BAT file

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, windows-command-prompt, pstools

Using PSEXEC to call CMD for a DEL command on a remote computer through a batch script.

```
PSEXEC \\hostname -u username -p password CMD /C DEL /Q /F C:\Folder\File.txt
```

The script pauses with a new CMD window popped up connected to the remote machine.

Why will psexec not automatically pass my DEL command via CMD?

EDIT:

The command works fine when sent directly through the CLI and not in a batch script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just run:

```
del /q \\hostname\c$\FolderFile\File.txt
```

Otherwise, write thet batch file on your system, then use the -c switch of psexec to "Copy the specified program to the remote system for execution"

Answer (score 0):

Your example command works fine in my test running in a batch file on Windows 7 targeting Windows XP, which is strange.

You could try enclosing your del command in quotes:

```
PSEXEC \\hostname-u username -p password CMD /C "DEL /Q /F C:\test.txt"
```